# Reading in a .csv file and calling a function on it

Tags: r

Im reading in a .csv and would like to perform a function on it. So therefore I do:

Function I want to call

```
award_test <- function(df) {

  df$rating_weging <- 0

  for (rows in 1:nrow(df)){
   if((df$won[rows] == "W") && (df$verschil[rows] > 0.6)){
    df$rating_weging[rows] <- 0.75
  }
 }
return(df)
}
```

Read in the .csv file and perform the function on it.

```
set <- function(){

setwd("dir")
   df <- read.csv("club_Barcelona.csv", header = T)

   #perform function
   award_test(df)

   write.csv(df,"club_Barcelona.csv")  
   setwd("dir")
 }
```

But my I run this my df does not not change. I do not see a column rating_weging...

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Comment: df <- award_test(df)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you have not saved the function's output.
As mentioned in the other answers, `df <- award_test(df)` should do the trick.

**Section not specifically related to the question , but could be useful to the OP**

*Since OP seems to be relatively new to R, I would like to point out that there are much cleaner ( possibly faster) ways than looping over all rows.*

For instance, `ifelse` could be useful in this case.

```
df$rating_weging = ifelse((df$won == 'W' & df$verschil > 0.6),0.75,0)
```

It assigns a particular value if a condition is satisfied , in this case 0.75 and another if it is not. ( in this case 0 ).

You can infact replace your entire function body with this statement!

Looping tends to be quite slow in R in many cases.

Take a look at this for more : 
http://www.r-bloggers.com/for-loops-and-how-to-avoid-them/

Answer (score 0):

When calling your `award_test` function within `set`, you don't save its output. As @Ven Yao has pointed, you should do a simple change in your `set` function:

```
set <- function(){

setwd("dir")
   df <- read.csv("club_Barcelona.csv", header = T)

   #perform function
   df <- award_test(df)

   write.csv(df,"club_Barcelona.csv")  
   setwd("dir")
 }
```